# AudioClip chopped and delaying audio play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help with a sound problem I found while programming a game.

I have an event (pointer click) and I need to play a sound inside that event.

To play the sound I'm using:

```
 AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(pop, transform.position, 1f);
```

After the instruction I have a bunch of lines with code and then I reload the scene to restart all over again.

So far, the sound is played but is chopped by the scene reload (I guess...), so I try using a delay

```
 IEnumerator WaitingForSomething()
     {
         UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Before Waiting");
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
         UnityEngine.Debug.Log("After Waiting");
         print(Time.time);
     }
```

but it didn't work. Google lead me to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/816650/c-yield-waitforseconds-not-working-1.html) answer about the execution of WaitForSeconds(). My WaitingForSomething() never print the after waiting debug or the Time.time because when it reach the yield return, it returns to where it was before and the next 50 lines of code are executed so fast that the 2 seconds are chopped by the scene reload.

So my questions are:

1. How can I enforce the full playback of the AudioClip?
2. If I can't enforce the full playback of the AudioClip, is there a way to force Unity3D to stop and wait until the AudioClip is fully played?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerator WaitForSound()
{
//PlaySound
yield return new WaitForSeconds(audioClip.lenght)// audioClip is the sound you are playing , this just pseudo code
Application.LoadLevel("SomeLevelname");
}
```

Just do all the code you need before calling the load level and use this I enumerator to play the sound, wait for its duration and then load the level.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Sorry but this solution is unpractical. The sound is the very first thing I need to do inside the event, and the reload the very last. Putting the reload will omite the rest of the code that I need to execute after the sound but before the reload.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should simplify it. Unity itself gives you the simplest of ways to add an audio source. have you tried adding the audio source component to the object in the hierarchy which you want the audio source to play from? also make sure your audio listener is parented to an object close to the audio source and there should only be one audio listener in the scene. Any audio clip can be added to the audio source however long it is and the option to loop is available.

Comment: @A.Njunguna Thank you for answering. The problem is not how I play the sound. Right now I'm using the first method explained in the first answer here: [https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/2rk7sp/playing_audioclip_with_script_c/](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/2rk7sp/playing_audioclip_with_script_c/), and the audio is cut, it never plays fully. I also try the second method wich is pretty much what you are suggesting, same results. The rest of the code **after** the sound execute in less than one second so the audio file never plays completely.